# Using context providers inside of React server components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to understand the reason why we should not use providers or any client components at the root of our application(or even higher up in the component hierarchy).

As I understand it, the server components are first turned into HTML and then streamed to the user's browser and client components are bundled separately and sent to client as javascript.

So when I add a server component as a child of a client component, while rendering, the client component would need to rendered first and the an already rendered server component be injected inside of it or...?

To setup a context provider, inside of a next application's app router, I need to create a file for providers and use "use client" at the top and then add the `children`

```
// providers.tsx

"use client"

import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from "next-themes"
import { ThemeProviderProps } from "next-themes/dist/types"

export function ThemeProvider({ children, ...props }: ThemeProviderProps) {
  return <NextThemesProvider {...props}>{children}</NextThemesProvider>
}
```

```
// layout.tsx

import ThemeProvider from "./providers"

export default function RootLayout({children}){
  return <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
}
```

Now my question is, If i use this provider at the root of my application, would all of the child components be client components by default. If so, then why do i need to explicitly use "use client" inside of all of the child components?

This is what the docs say

> Once "use client" is defined in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.